# Getting exception of A RenderFlex overflowed by 203 pixels on the bottom in flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed6bl.png)We trying to run my flutter code am getting this exception 'A RenderFlex overflowed by 203 pixels on the bottom', and the exception is pointing at the first child column of my code. i have try wrapping the column with SingleChildScrollView, Expanded and Flexible but still am getting same exception.

.............................................................................
My Code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
              colors: [
                Color(0xFF3594DD),
                Color(0xFF4563DB),
                Color(0xFF5036D5),
                Color(0xFF5B16D0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => print('Skip'),
                    child: Text(
                      'Skip',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 600.0,
                  child: PageView(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _pageController,
                    onPageChanged: (int page) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentPage = page;
                      });
                    },
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/onboarding0.png',
                                ),
                                height: 150.0,
                                width: 150.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Connect people\naround the world',
                              style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                              style: kSubtitleStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/onboarding1.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Live your life smarter\nwith us!',
                              style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                              style: kSubtitleStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/onboarding2.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Get a new experience\nof imagination',
                              style: kTitleStyle,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                              style: kSubtitleStyle,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: _buildPageIndicator(),
                ),
                _currentPage != _numPages - 1
                    ? Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _pageController.nextPage(
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.ease,
                              );
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Next',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 22.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(''),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: _currentPage == _numPages - 1
          ? Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => print('Get started'),
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Get started',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Text(''),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you post a screenshot since this is a UI issue?

Comment: Okay sir, i have updated my post with the screenshot link

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the first `Container` widget with a `SingleChildScrollView` and then remove the `Expanded` after this check  `_currentPage != _numPages - 1`.

Your new code should be:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
                colors: [
                  Color(0xFF3594DD),
                  Color(0xFF4563DB),
                  Color(0xFF5036D5),
                  Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () => print('Skip'),
                      child: Text(
                        'Skip',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 600.0,
                    child: PageView(
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: _pageController,
                      onPageChanged: (int page) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentPage = page;
                        });
                      },
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Center(
                                child: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage(
                                    'assets/images/onboarding0.png',
                                  ),
                                  height: 150.0,
                                  width: 150.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                              Text(
                                'Connect people\naround the world',
                                style: kTitleStyle,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                              Text(
                                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                                style: kSubtitleStyle,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Center(
                                child: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage(
                                    'assets/images/onboarding1.png',
                                  ),
                                  height: 300.0,
                                  width: 300.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                              Text(
                                'Live your life smarter\nwith us!',
                                style: kTitleStyle,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                              Text(
                                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                                style: kSubtitleStyle,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Center(
                                child: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage(
                                    'assets/images/onboarding2.png',
                                  ),
                                  height: 300.0,
                                  width: 300.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                              Text(
                                'Get a new experience\nof imagination',
                                style: kTitleStyle,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                              Text(
                                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                                style: kSubtitleStyle,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: _buildPageIndicator(),
                  ),
                  _currentPage != _numPages - 1
                      ? Align(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _pageController.nextPage(
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                              curve: Curves.ease,
                            );
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Next',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 22.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_forward,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 30.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                      : Text(''),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: _currentPage == _numPages - 1
          ? Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => print('Get started'),
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Get started',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Text(''),
    );
  }
```